# XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress"... not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest

I try to populate an upload bar by calling *XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);*. Apparently my function *progressHandler* is not called at all. I do not have a clue, why.

Everything else works fine, e.g. the call of *completeHandler*, after the file is completely uploaded. The upload of my testfile takes approx. 15 secs, so I would expect *progressHandler* to be called.

Maybe someone can help me?

```
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("uploadfilename", file);
    formdata.append("inte", ticketid);
    formdata.append("username", userName);
    formdata.append("custname", custName);
    formdata.append("userlastname", userLastName);
    formdata.append("par", par);
    formdata.append("mod", mod);

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false); 
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "mod/intern/uploader_upload_done.php", false);
    ajax.send(formdata);

    var response = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
    // parsing response
    ....


    function progressHandler(event)
    {
       var percent = 100 *(event.loaded / event.total);
       _("fortschritt").value = Math.round(percent);
       _("fortschritt_txt").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% done...";
    }


    function completeHandler(event)
    { 
      _("fortschritt_txt").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
      _("fortschritt").value = 100;
     _("ticketid").value = '';
   }


   function errorHandler(event)
   { 
      _("fortschritt_txt").innerHTML = "Upload failed";
   } 


    function abortHandler(event)
    {
      _("fortschritt_txt").innerHTML = "Upload cancelled";
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is supported in the browser you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are uploading the file synchronously, try changing the `open()` call to

```
 ajax.open("POST", "mod/intern/uploader_upload_done.php", true);
```